# Can you disable power from LG Ultrafine monitor to Mac?

Tags: macos

I am experiencing a potential known issue of second monitor not waking when system wakes from sleep.  I have done the perquisite resets of SMC and NVRAM and have been working with Apple support to a very deep level.  To no avail.  There seems to be an issue where system does not respond as expected when there are multiple power sources.  Is there a way to disable the power flow from the LG Ultrafine 4k monitors?  I will just rely on the wall.  I have a 2017 15" MBPro with Radeon Pro 560.  I have tested on MacOS 10.12.5 and MacOS 10.13 Beta (17A291m). Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to disrupt power via command.  If you want a convenient solution, consider a [remote controlled electrical outlet](http://amzn.to/2ttmi4a).  It's a total hack, but should solve the issue so you don't have to plug/unplug all the time.

Comment: No worse than my current hack of unplugging the monitor from the MBPro and plugging back in!

Comment: Maybe a bit more convenient...you won't have to reach for the cord.

Comment: Please disregard.  the issue that led to this odd question has been resolved with an recent LG firmware update

Comment: Then this is the answer - type it up and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Please disregard. the issue that led to this odd question has been resolved with an recent LG firmware update.

I have two UltraFine 4K monitors connected to a 2016 MBPro. When the Mac went to sleep both displays went to sleep, but only one would wake.

This has been resolved by the latest firmware.

1.) InstaLL LG Screen Manager. LG site still showing old version.
2.) It will push the most recent version. v2.06.
3.) Upgrade your monitor to the latest firmware. (3.11, 3.4, 5226, 3.04, 0.2f)